# JDBC Connections not released till end of thread

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere

I have a websphere application server with an MSSQL database connection with 10 in the connection pool. When my worker thread runs I have a process that runs the following:

```
Psuedo code

for(List<String> items){
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try{
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "exec someStoredProcedure '" + item + "';";
        statement.execute(sql);
    }finally{
        //real code includes null checks and try catch for errors
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

My problem is that if my loop is larger than 10 it will hang till it hits the timeout and error "ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: J2CA1010E: Connection not available; timed out waiting for 180 seconds".

I would think that closing the statements and connections would allow me to reuse the connection from the pool. The connections do get closed/collected after the thread finishes. I've updated my code to reuse the same connection through the for loop and I can run the process rapid fire over and over without problems because each thread cleans up after itself it seems. Any idea what's going on or how to resolve? I'm worried in the future I'll have a process that needs more than 10 threads over the course of running.

Comment: It is probably because your connections are being contained within a local transaction (LTC).  The LTC won't commit or rollback until the method returns which means the connections wont be returned to the free pool.  I believe you can resolve this by using shared connections, or a user transaction.

Comment: Show your real code

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show real code due to company regulations.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you describe sounds inconsistent with how the connection pool is supposed to work. However, there are a number of important details that impact connection reuse which are not apparent from your writeup.

You are either using sharable or unsharable connections. You can find that out by looking at the resource reference that you used for the DataSource lookup. For example, `@Resource` with `shareable=false` or a deployment descriptor resource reference with `<res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>` is unsharable, whereas if you set true for the former or Shareable for the latter or omit the attribute, then the connection is sharable. If you didn't use a resource reference, connections will typically be sharable, unless you explicitly overrode that with advanced configuration.

If you are using an unsharable connection and the entire code block is not encompassed within a global transaction, then every connection.close will return the connection to the pool to become immediately reusable.  If you are in a global transaction, then each connection will remain unavailable after close because there is outstanding work on it that still needs to be committed or rolled back.

If you are using a sharable connection and each of the connection requests match (same user/password or absence thereof for all), then you should keep getting the same underlying connection back and should not run out of connections. If however, the connection requests do not match, then the connections are kept around for the duration of the scope (could be a transaction or a request scope like servlet boundary) and you will keep getting a new connection with each request until you run out.

If the above isn't enough to figure out the issue, add more detail to your scenario indicating the sharability, how you request each connections, and the placement of transaction boundaries and request boundaries, so that a more detailed answer for your specific scenario can be given.